# Access array returned by function in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a total brain freeze trying to get an array passed back from a function so that I can then access its values. The function is as follows:

```
function queryKeys($value) {

    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM um_taxkeys WHERE key_id = 1334";
    $key = $wpdb->get_row( $query );

    $array["value_en"] = $key->name_en;
    $array["value_es"] = $key->name_es;
    $array["value_de"] = $key->name_de;


    return $array;
    //var_dump($array);

}
```

...and I've tried accessing it using:

```
...
queryKeys($value);
echo $array['value_es'];
...
```

...but I am getting confused on the correct syntax to use to get values back from the returned array. Appreciate some guidance please. Many thanks.

Comment: What does the function queryKeys do?  It's not a valid PHP core function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss return value assignment:

```
$array = queryKeys($values);
echo $array['value_es'];
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand where I was going wrong. You need to set the array for the returned $value that comes back first. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
<?php
$array = queryKeys($value);
echo $array['value_es'];
```